# css background-image doesn't work on table object

Tags: html, css, django

in my Django app I would like to put a background image in a table. The problem is that the image doesn't show. This is the code:

```
<table style="background-image: url('/static/assets/img/myimage.png') ;background-position: 0 100% !important;background-repeat: repeat-x ;background-size: 40px 3px">
Hello!
</table>
```

If I put the same css style in div object all work. Eg:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/static/assets/img/myimage.png') ;background-position: 0 100% !important;background-repeat: repeat-x ;background-size: 40px 3px">
Hello!
</div>
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks a lot for the help

EDIT1

I would like to insert a email html file in a django template. I use 'include' and all works for  image but doesn't works for background-image style. The image location is correct (if I use 'div' and not 'table' all works). I have bootstrap

EDIT2

This the complete code. In the table I don't see the background image

```
<!-- ======= section ======= -->
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="34302d" style="background-image: url('http://themastermail.com/envato/omail/demo/layout2/img/testi-bg.jpg') !important; background-size: cover; background-position: top center; background-repeat: no-repeat;" background="http://themastermail.com/envato/omail/demo/layout2/img/testi-bg.jpg">

    <tr><td height="60" style="font-size: 60px; line-height: 60px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">

            <table border="0" width="590" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container590">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" width="580" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container580">

                            <tr>

                                <td align="center" style="color: #b9bcc7; font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Open Sans', Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 30px;" class="title_color">
                                    <!-- ======= section text ====== -->

                                    <div style="line-height: 30px">

                                            <em>Proin eget massa tincidunt, lobortis ex nec, placerat odio. Mauris gravida nulla id laoreet ornare. Maecenas sagittis elit metus, eget pellentesque couleur non categorize rouge vert bleu.</em>

                                    </div>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td height="35" style="font-size: 35px; line-height: 35px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" width="80">
                                    <a href="" style=" border-style: none !important; border: 0 !important;"><img src="http://themastermail.com/envato/omail/demo/layout2/img/testi-img.png" style="display: block; width: auto;" width="70" border="0" alt=""/></a>
                                </td>

                                <td align="left" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px; font-family: Raleway, Calibri, sans-serif; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 24px;" class="title_color">

                                    <!-- ======= section header ======= -->

                                    <div style="line-height: 24px;">

                                            Marta Clarcks<br><a href="" style="color: #f29a27; text-decoration: none;">envato.com</a>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td height="60" style="font-size: 60px; line-height: 60px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

</table>
<!-- ======= end section ====== -->
```

Comment: do your table cells have any styling?

Comment: Yes, is an email template. The td style are varius

Comment: `<table style="background-image: url('/static/assets/img/myimage.png') ! important...` you left out the `!` sign in your code.

Comment: thanks for your response but doeasn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `!` on your `!important` tag.

```
<table style="background-image: url('/static/assets/img/myimage.png') !important;background-position: 0 100% !important;background-repeat: repeat-x !;background-size: 40px 3px">
Hello!
</table>
```

but as you've not got a `tr`, `td` etc in your field it may still not display it, you should try:

```
<table style="background-image: url('/static/assets/img/myimage.png') !important;background-position: 0 100% !important;background-repeat: repeat-x !;background-size: 40px 3px; display: block;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>hello</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i cant get it to break, here's a pen with it working fine:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adGoKz

Is it not displaying on all browsers etc?

Comment: I found the error. There are two css that set the table background color to #fff and so the image doesn't show. Really a stupid mistake I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <table style="background-image: url('static/assets/img/myimage.png') !important;background-position: 0 100% !important;background-repeat: repeat-x !;background-size: 40px 3px">
    <tr><td>Hello!</td></tr>
    </table>
```

folder structure 
css.css
static/

Comment: Thanks a lot. With tr and td works. In the code example that I have put doesn't work. I'm sorry

Comment: remove leading slash "/static" , and make sure css files and static folder both in same folder

Comment: I found the error. There are two css that set the table background color to #fff and so the image doesn't show. Really a stupid mistake I'm sorry.